# Regex pattern for this string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem to match some string in fallowing lines:

```
02-16 12:23:24.046  3068  3068 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:153) 
02-16 12:23:24.046  3068  3068 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:559)
02-16 12:23:24.046  3068  3068 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2716)
02-16 12:23:24.046  3068  3068 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2151)
02-16 12:23:24.046  3068  3068 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-16 12:23:24.046  3068  3068 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
02-16 12:23:24.046  3068  3068 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

And i want to match string between two last '(' ')' chars. I know there is a lot of regex tutorials, but i just cannot get it yet. I need to study more about this

So result of success should be:

```
WindowManagerImpl.java:153
Window.java:559
ActivityThread.java:2716
ActivityThread.java:2151
and so on
```

All i know is that there is not always word "java", so I want to take value between last "(" ")"

Thank you all for any clues

Comment: Why you need regex? Logcat is TAB delimited IIRC.

Comment: What does it have to do with design patterns ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You could also simply use `Substring` and `LastIndexOf`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are no other parenthesis in the line then something like this would work:

```
\([^)]+\)
```

You could then trim the ( and ) off the ends of the match.

Or group in inner text:

```
\(([^)]+)\)
```

And then use match.Groups[1].Value to get value of the inner group.

Update: And @cabecao reminded me, if the text always appears at the end, and there might be other parenthesis then add a "$" at the end to match the end of a line.

```
\([^)]+\)$
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=\().*(?=\))");
foreach (Match item in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\)$)
```

Using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to make extracting the result easier. It will match a group of non-parenthesis characters preceded by one and followed by one at the [end of the string](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I can think of now:

```
.*\((.*)\)$
```